A "HID-compliant mouse" and a "USB composite device", both have no records in their "Device Manager - Properties - Events"
A "HID-compliant mouse" and a "USB composite device", both have no records in their "Device Manager - Properties - Events". Both are "currently not connected".
All other "Mice and other pointing devices" have records indicating "Device Configured" and "Device Started" with timestamps.
Malicious?

First rule out the mundane before jumping to the malicious

@schroeder Velly vise me lord

@jsotola How about "devices without event logs can be normal under certain situations"? Like system automatically purges old logs?

comments are not for you to ask questions ... please edit your post instead
